# How would i implode to get the right values of a GET request

Tags: php

i am currently trying to get every value stated in a $_GET code but how would i manage to do just so?

I've tried to foreach them imploding id- and letting it know that its the ID

```
/?id-3=143&id-4=49&id-5=94&id-6=94&id-7=2660&id-8=2611&id-13=49&id-14=49&id-15=49&id-16=49&id-17=49&id-18=49&id-9=49&id-19=49&id-10=49&saveloge=1
```

Code

```
<select name="id-<?php echo $electdata['id'];?>" form="gemloge">
    <?php foreach ( $members as $member ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $member['userid'];?>"<?php if($member['userid'] == $userid) { echo 'selected';}?>><?php echo $member['title'] . ' ' . $member['firstname'] . ' ' . $member['lastname']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I want to gather the information transmitted by the $_GET but how am i supposed to know which one is which? these are not Static.

I want to Update values in database where id-xx is the id of the select menu stated in db.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between `value="someValue"selected` ?

Comment: `name="id[<?php echo $electdata['id'];?>]"`, then you get an array in `$_GET['id']` that you can easily loop over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the entire `$_GET` array, and use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to check if the key starts with `id-` (Then pulling out the actual `$id` afterwards)

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    if ( substr($key, 0, 3) === "id-" ) {
        $id = substr($key, 3);
        // Do stuff with $id (Which has $value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!